# Why does this definition of derivative make sense?

Tags: calculus

[image]

This is from Munkres analysis on manifolds.

Why does $A$ have to contain the neighbourhood of the point $a$? What’s the reasoning behind this? What happens if it’s not included in the definition?

Comment: If you don't make that assumption, you may not be able to even compute $\phi (a+t)$ because $a+t$ could lie outside the domain of $\phi$.

Comment: Oops sorry  I was think about this for an hour but couldn’t figure it out. So trivial. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be able to compute $\phi (a+t)$,  at least for small $t$. The assumption you mention assures that $a+t$ belongs to the domain $A$ (at least for small enough $t$).